# How can I change the original code to always add `top: false` in my SafeArea widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to use "statusBarColor: Colors.transparent", on all views, I can do this with ThemeData besides, I have to use SafeArea(top: false,) like this, yeah this is a solution but I have to use SafeArea(top: false) on all view,

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
.........
```

[image]

I didn't find any solution with ThemeData, so I was either going to use it on all views I have or I was going to change the original code(safe_area.dart). If I do, this is what I want and this fits perfectly in my situation.

question => to change original code is bad idea ? or good idea ? in what case should we do this, or should we do it?
[image]

Comment: What about placing the SafeArea in top of the very first widget?

Comment: If I understand your questin correctly: you want to always use `top: false` in `SafeArea` widget?

Comment: yes I want to always use top:false in SafeArea widget

Comment: placing the SafeArea on top of the very first widget? --> I use the push route, push means to get a new page and if a new page has not SafeArea this doesn't work. this is what I know, any way this works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To always add `top: false` whenever you call a `SafeArea()`,
you can create your own class that `extends` `SafeArea`:

```dart
class mySafeArea extends SafeArea {
   Widget child;

  mySafeArea({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
  }) : super(
            key: key,
            child: child,
            top: false,
            bottom: true,
            left: true,
            right: true,
            minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
            maintainBottomViewPadding: false);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(child: child);
  }
}
```

Then call `mySafeArea()` instead of `SafeArea()`

Comment: this works too, thanks, what about you think to change the original code? this is a bad idea?

Comment: @Sky Obviously this is a bad idea.